# When refreshing materialised views does the index automatically refresh

Tags: oracle

When refreshing materialised views does the index automatically refresh

Answer (score 7):

**Yes.**

A refresh changes the table storing the data that is materialized from the materialized view query.  The indexes for these tables are updated just as indexes for "normal" tables would be updated when they change.

Comment: An exception would be Oracle Text indexes for full text search (eg on CLOBS, PDFs etc) which require a synchronize operation.